# I am trying to Implement Afnetworking in my project without pod just copy paste the files in my project but it is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, xcode7

In 3.0 Afnetworking I am copying AFNetworking, UIKit+AFNetworking and importing AFNetworking.h but getting error

I want to know how to implement Afnetworking without pod

Could some one help me on this...

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * manager =[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]init];
[manager POST:@"http://192.168.1.92/Abdul/Json/student.json" parameters:@"" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"RESULT .. %@",responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"ERR .. %@",error);

}];
```

Comment: 1.use of undeclared identifier AFHTTPRequestOperationManager   2. use of undeclared identifier manager

Comment: what is your version of Xcode?

Comment: I copy AFNetworking folder from github and Import AFNetworking.h file

Comment: My Xcode version is 7.1, same problem is shown, so i change the AFNetworking 2.4 version then work perfectly no error shown when import the AFNetworking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you using latest verson of **afnetwork 3.x**

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.92/Abdul/Json/student.json"];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager POST:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil   success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

if you using oldest verson of **afnetwork 2.x**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://192.168.1.92/Abdul/Json/student.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

**Note**

check once are you imported the header file

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h> // or #import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
```

Comment: header file not found for #import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h> // or #import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan -  are you using cocoapods or direct

Comment: Sending form data and username password. using directly not using cocoapods. But works fine with #import <AFNetworking.h>